# not using [parameter()] on some parameters in a PowerShell advanced function

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

If you are doing advanced functions and have the parameters decorated [parameter()], would there be any reason to NOT decorate a parameter with [Parameter()] . I've seen this a few times and don't know whether its just a case of laziness, oversight, or purposeful design.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Laziness I think but to be fair, it isn't needed if you aren't using any special parameter attibutes like `Mandatory`, `Position`, etc.  As long is one parameter is marked `[Parameter(...)]` or the param block is marked `[CmdletBinding(...)]` PowerShell will interpret that function as an advanced function.  OTOH there is no harm in adding the empty `[Parameter()]` to parameters.

Comment: Yeah i think though if you are using it on any, its probably best to be consistent, especially if you are doing some parametersets IMO.

Comment: FWIW, that is what I usually do.

Comment: It is probably best to put them on all parameters... but I do tend to leave them off of switches.